# Remove <br /> with some condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a html templte to send a mail as given below.

```
<br />
<strong>FirstName</strong><br />
{FirstName}<br />
<br />
<strong>LastName</strong><br />
{LastName}<br />
<br />
<strong>Address</strong><br />
{Address}<br />
<br />
<strong>BirthDate</strong><br />
{BirthDate}<br />
<br />
```

here I get value from database table and replace respective values with {FirstName}, {LastName}, {Address} and {BirthDate}.

Now If there is no value in database table for any field then I want to remove those field from html template. For Example if there is no Address in table I want to remove Address
{Address}
from template.

I have used folowwing code :

```
 strContent = strContent.Replace("<strong>" + Address + "</strong><br />", " ");
 strContent = strContent.Replace("{" + Address  + "}<br />", "");
```

Code works fine but it does not remove break new line. I mean there is two blank line between Lastname and Birthdate. So How to remove those two blank line.

I have use following code to remove break line but it removes all break line from all fields.

```
  strContent = strContent.Replace("<br />", " ");
```

Comment: consider adjusting template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `Replace` replaces `"{" + Address  + "}<br />"`, where you're actually looking for `"{" + Address  + "}<br />\r\n<br />"` to remove the newline and `<br />` that follow.

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as non-elegant solution, but might work in you case:

```
<strong><br />FirstName</strong><br />
    {FirstName}<br />

    <strong><br />LastName</strong><br />
    {LastName}<br />

    <strong><br />Address</strong><br />
    {Address}<br />

    <strong><br />BirthDate</strong><br />
    {BirthDate}<br />
    <br />
```

Your code:

```
strContent = strContent.Replace("<strong><br />" + Address + "</strong><br />", " ");
strContent = strContent.Replace("{" + Address  + "}<br />", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways of doing this.
If you prefer working with a model of the html, you could use the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to work with the HTML as a DOM. Of course, this is a new API.

Otherwise, I see two options: do some string manipulations that will need adjusting if you ever need to change the template, or use two templates, and have the presence or absence of an address determine which template to use.

If you're determined to use string manipulation, then I'd suggest adding some markup to the HTML template to make easy to find start and stop points for each field:

```
<br />
<strong>FirstName</strong><br />
{FirstName}<br />
<br />
<strong>LastName</strong><br />
{LastName}<br />
<br />
<div id="addressField">
    <strong>Address</strong><br />
    {Address}<br />
    <br />
</div>
<strong>BirthDate</strong><br />
{BirthDate}<br />
<br />
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
int addressStartIdx = strContent.IndexOf(@"<div id="addressField">");
int addressCount = strContent.Substring(addressStartIdx).IndexOf(@"</div>");
// IndexOf gives the position of the first character of the string,
// so we need to account for the rest of the string
addressCount += @"</div>".Length;     

strContent = strContent.Remove(addressStartIdx, addressCount);
```

This is more involved than CodeCaster's answer, though.